# Extract form field value with pdf.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I have the following implementation of pdf.js into a small component that loads a pdf on the screen:

```
<template id="embeddedpdf">
    <v-card v-if="disabled == true" style="aspect-ratio: 1; width:100%" class="pa-3 ma-3">
        <v-container class="d-flex" fill-height fluid>
            <v-row class="align-center justify-center">
                <v-icon x-large>fas fa-lock</v-icon>
            </v-row>
        </v-container>
    </v-card>
    <v-card v-else-if="disabled == false && timeout == true" style="aspect-ratio: 1; width:100%" class="pa-3 ma-3">
        <v-container>
            <v-card-title>
                <v-menu bottom
                        right>
                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                        <v-btn light
                               icon
                               v-bind="attrs"
                               v-on="on">
                            <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
                        </v-btn>
                    </template>
                    <v-list>
                        <template v-for="(item,index) in menus">
                            <v-list-item v-if="item.isActive" :key="index" v-on:click="$emit(item.clickFunction)" link>
                                <v-list-item-title>{{item.title}}</v-list-item-title>
                            </v-list-item>
                        </template>
                        <v-list-item :href="downloadlink" download link>
                            <v-list-item-title>Download</v-list-item-title>
                        </v-list-item>
                    </v-list>
                </v-menu>
            </v-card-title>
        </v-container>
    </v-card>
    <v-card v-else-if="disabled == false && loadingFile == true && timeout == false" style="aspect-ratio: 1; width:100%" class="pa-3 ma-3">
        <v-container class="d-flex" fill-height fluid>
            <v-row class="align-center justify-center">
                <v-progress-circular :size="100"
                                     color="secondary"
                                     class="my-16"
                                     indeterminate></v-progress-circular>
            </v-row>
        </v-container>
    </v-card>
    <v-card v-else-if="disabled == false && loadingFile == false && timeout == false" style="aspect-ratio: 1; width:100%" class="pa-3 ma-3">
        <v-container>
            <v-card-title>
                <v-menu bottom
                        right>

                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                        <v-btn light
                               icon
                               v-bind="attrs"
                               v-on="on">
                            <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
                        </v-btn>
                    </template>
                    <v-list>
                        <template v-for="(item,index) in menus">
                            <v-list-item v-if="item.isActive" :key="index" link>
                                <v-list-item-title v-on:click="$emit(item.clickFunction)">{{item.title}}</v-list-item-title>
                            </v-list-item>
                        </template>
                        <v-list-item :href="downloadlink" download link>
                            <v-list-item-title>Download</v-list-item-title>
                        </v-list-item>
                    </v-list>
                </v-menu>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <span>
                    <v-btn light
                           icon
                           @@click="fullscreenPDF()">
                        <v-icon light>mdi-fullscreen</v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                </span>
            </v-card-title>
            <canvas :id="canvasid" class="the-canvas"></canvas>
            <v-row class="justify-center align-self-end">
                <v-btn class="mx-2"
                       fab
                       dark
                       small
                       color="primary"
                       outlined
                       @@click="onPrevPage">
                    <v-icon dark>
                        mdi-rewind
                    </v-icon>
                </v-btn>
                <v-btn class="mx-2"
                       fab
                       dark
                       small
                       color="primary"
                       outlined
                       @@click="onNextPage">
                    <v-icon dark>
                        mdi-fast-forward
                    </v-icon>
                </v-btn>
            </v-row>
        </v-container>
    </v-card>
</template>
<script>
    Vue.component('embeddedpdf',
    {
        template: '#embeddedpdf',
        props: {
            base64string: {
                type: String,
            },
            canvasid: {
                type: String,
            },
            disabled: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false,
                required: false,
            },
            menus: {
                type: Array,
                default: () => [],
                required: false,
            },
            downloadlink: {
                type: String,
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                pageNum: 1,
                pageNumPending: null,
                pageRendering: false,
                totalPageCount: null,
                loadingFile: true,
                dialog: false,
                exists: true,
                timeout: false,
            }  
        },
        methods: {
            renderPage(num) {
                pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =
                    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/3.5.141/pdf.worker.min.js";
                var pdfData = atob(this.base64string);
                var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data: pdfData });
                
                loadingTask.promise.then(
                    this.loadPDF, function (reason) {
                    // PDF loading error
                    console.error(reason);
                });
            },
            loadPDF(pdf) {
                //console.log('PDF loaded');
                if (this.pageRendering == false) {
                    // Fetch the first page
                    this.pageRendering = true;
                    //console.log("number of pages " + pdf.numPages);
                    this.totalPageCount = pdf.numPages;

                    pdf.getPage(this.pageNum).then(this.loadPage);
                }
            },
            loadPage(page) {
                //console.log('Page loaded');
                var scale = 1.5;
                var viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale });

                // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
                var canvas = document.getElementById(this.canvasid);
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                canvas.width = viewport.width;

                // Render PDF page into canvas context
                var renderContext = {
                    canvasContext: context,
                    viewport: viewport
                };
                var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
                renderTask.promise.then(this.rendering);
            },
            rendering() {
                //console.log('Page rendered');
                this.pageRendering = false;
                if (this.pageNumPending != null) {
                    // New page rendering is pending
                    this.renderPage(this.pageNumPending);
                    this.pageNumPending = null;
                }
            },
            queueRenderPage(num) {
                if (this.pageRendering) {
                    this.pageNumPending = num;
                } else {
                    this.renderPage(num);
                }
            },
            onPrevPage() {

                if (this.pageNum <= 1) {
                    return;
                }
                this.pageNum--;
                this.queueRenderPage(this.pageNum);
            },
            onNextPage() {
                if (this.pageNum >= this.totalPageCount) {
                    return;
                }
                this.pageNum++;
                this.queueRenderPage(this.pageNum);
            },
            async checkFileExist(path, timeout = 50000) {

                let totalTime = 0;
                let checkTime = 2000;
                var self = this;

                return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const timer = setInterval(function () {

                        totalTime += checkTime;

                        if (totalTime <= timeout) {
                            let fileExists = self.fileExist(path);

                            if (fileExists) {
                                clearInterval(timer);
                                resolve(fileExists);

                            }
                        } else {
                            reject("File not found and pdf loader timed out")
                        }
                    }, checkTime);
                })
            },
            fileExist(urlToFile) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('HEAD', urlToFile, false);
                xhr.send();

                if (xhr.status == "404") {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            },
            setupFunction() {
                this.timeout = false
                var self = this
                if (this.base64string == null || this.base64string == "") {
                    self.loadingFile = true;
                } else {
                    self.loadingFile = false;
                    if (self.pageRendering == false) {
                        self.renderPage(this.pageNum);
                    }
                }
            },
            resolveYourReview: function() {
                alert('test')
            },
            fullscreenPDF() {

                var base64str = this.base64string;

                // decode base64 string, remove space for IE compatibility
                var binary = atob(base64str.replace(/\s/g, ''));
                var len = binary.length;
                var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(len);
                var view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    view[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
                }

                // create the blob object with content-type "application/pdf"               
                var blob = new Blob([view], { type: "application/pdf" });
                var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                window.open(url);
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.setupFunction()
        },
        watch: {
            base64string: function () { // watch it
                this.setupFunction()
            },
            disabled: function () { // watch it
                this.setupFunction()
            },
            menuItemsArray: function () {
                //this.setupFunction()
            }
        }
     })
</script>
<style scoped>
    .the-canvas {
        width:100%; 
        height: auto; 
    }

</style>
```

This component will load the base64 string of the pdf into the viewer and display everything and if not or still loading will use a vuetify loader icon or lock icon if its is locked for viewing. However, I am trying to pull values from this pdf. Say I have a form field with a textbox with field name 'Test'. How do I pull the form value inside this text box? Is not not possible with pdf.js and require some other library to achieve this?

Comment: I think you are correct about pdf.js. I am looking for a library that might fix this. I will look into PDF-lib though. I need to work from the cdn so if they have one I can add it to my project.